# DBCC Shrinkfile after full backup restoration but before differential restoration

Tags: sql-server, backup, shrink, dbcc, truncate

My database full backup file size is 760 GB and differential would be around 20 GB but the database size is around 2TB. As it is a production database, so to apply only a minimum downtime, i want to run DBCC SHRINKFILE with TRUNCATEONLY before restoring differential backup.

Please advise if i can run the command DBCC SHRINKFILE with TRUNCATEONLY after full backup restored but before differential backup restoration.

Comment: Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_ . Currently your question doesn't contain enough relevant information to  be answerable and will possibly be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). To answer your question: You can always run the SQL Server commands against a database. The questions you probably should be asking are: _Should I run the `DBCC SHRINKFILE...` command before or after the restore?_ and _Should I run the `DBCC SHRINKFILE...` at all?_

Comment: Please advise if i can run the command DBCC SHRINKFILE with TRUNCATEONLY between full backup restored and before differential backup restoration.

Answer (score 0):

> Please advise if i can run the command DBCC SHRINKFILE with
>   TRUNCATEONLY between full backup restored and before differential
>   backup restoration.

No, you cannot.

You'll get the error that your **database is in the middle of restore**, and this is logic, you cannot do anything with database that is restoring.

You should analyse your db free space using `sp_spaceused` to understand if you can and should do anything with this database BEFORE you take the last backup, may be your db is in the `full` recovery model and log backups are not made regularly?

Answer (score 0):

> Shrinking database has to be done after restore backups (any backup)
>   or before taking the backup.
>
> And you should Restore data-files as they were at the backup.

The following steps might give you what you need and shouldn't impact production:

- Run a `DBCC SHRINKFILE` (**'.MDF', TRUNCATEONLY**) on the production data file to temporarily release any free space at the end of the file (a TRUNCATEONLY is not IO intensive, and will not fragment indexes)
- If the log file is also big, run a `DBCC SHRINKFILE` on the production log file during a time of low activity, just after taking a log backup.
- After Run your backup
- Do an **ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE** to re-grow the production data file back to the original size.